# How do I output messages in ListView from PubNub method history()?

Tags: java, listview, pubnub

I have in my project (simple chat application) ListView of TextViews (messages). Here's code of publishing messages:

```
    public void publish(View view) {

    final EditText mMessage = (EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.new_message);

    final Map<String, String> message = ImmutableMap.<String, String>of("sender", MainActivity.this.nickName, "message", mMessage.getText().toString(), "timestamp", DateTimeUtil.getTimeStampUtc());
    MainActivity.this.mPubnub_DataStream.publish().channel(Constants.CHANNEL_NAME).shouldStore(true).message(message).async(
            new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                    try {
                        if (!status.isError()) {
                            mMessage.setText("");
                            Log.v(TAG, "publish(" + JsonUtil.asJson(result) + ")");
                        } else {
                            Log.v(TAG, "publishErr(" + JsonUtil.asJson(status) + ")");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

I'm trying to output messages from history:

```
this.mPubnub_DataStream.history()
                .channel(Constants.CHANNEL_NAME)
                .async(new PNCallback<PNHistoryResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PNHistoryResult result, PNStatus status) {

                    }
                });
```

I have no idea how to override onResponse method. Please help me. 
Btw, I can check if my messages are stored, but output to terminal is not what I really need.

```
pubNub.history()
                .channel(channelName)
                .count(100)
                .async(new PNCallback<PNHistoryResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PNHistoryResult result, PNStatus status) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                            System.out.println(result.getMessages().get(i).getEntry());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is more of a UI data binding question than a PubNub question, as long as you actually receiving messages from the `history` call. If you are then perhaps the sample code in this example app might be helpful: https://github.com/pubnub/webinar-android-intro - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a UI data binding question than a PubNub question, as long as you actually receiving messages from the history call.

If you are then perhaps the sample code in this example app might be helpful: github.com/pubnub/webinar-android-intro